How can I integrate AJAX infinite Scroll with Django View
I have a Django view that originally displays a list of applicants, and using the filter by session, it is expected to display list of applicants by the selected academic session. And using pagination, user is expected to scroll through pages using AJAX. The problem I am currently having is that records are been repeated in the list as the user scroll through the list and serial numbers are also repeated too.
See Django view code:

`@login_required(login_url='accounts_login')
def application_list_by_session(request):
    logged_user = request.user
    if not (logged_user.profile.role == 'ADMISSION-OFFICER' or logged_user.profile.role == 'Admin' or logged_user.profile.role == 'Super Admin' or logged_user.is_superuser):
        messages.warning(request, 'Something Went Wrong')
        return redirect('accounts_login')
# Log user activity
UserActivityLog.objects.create(user=logged_user, action='Visited Application List by Academic Session Page')

# Academic Session Form
form = ApplicationlistBySessionForm(request.GET or None)
if request.method == "GET" and form.is_valid():
    academic_session = form.cleaned_data['academic_session']

    # Filter Application by Academic Session
    submitted_application_list = ApplicationSubmission.objects.filter(academic_sess=academic_session)
    count_submited_applications = submitted_application_list.count()

    # Log user activity
    UserActivityLog.objects.create(user=logged_user, action=f' Generated Application list for {academic_session} Academic Session with {count_submited_applications} Applicants ')

    paginator = Paginator(submitted_application_list, 2)  # Change 10 to your desired number of items per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        submitted_applications = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        submitted_applications = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        submitted_applications = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    context = {
        'count_submited_applications': count_submited_applications,
        'academic_session': academic_session,
        'submitted_application_list': submitted_applications,
        'page_title': f'List of Applicants for {academic_session} Session',
    }

    # Check for download request
    if request.GET.get('download'):
        pdf_data = generate_pdf(request, submitted_application_list, context)
        if pdf_data:
            return pdf_data
        else:
            # Handle error when generating PDF
            messages.error(request, 'Error generating PDF')
            return redirect('application_list_by_session')

    if request.headers.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':  # If AJAX request
        return JsonResponse({'html': render_to_string('admission/application_list_by_session_ajax.html', context)})
    else:
        return render(request, 'admission/application_list_by_session.html', context)
else:
    form = ApplicationlistBySessionForm()

# List of all applicants
submitted_application_list = ApplicationSubmission.objects.order_by('-submitted_date')
paginator = Paginator(submitted_application_list, 10)  # Change 10 to your desired number of items per page

# Get page number with fallback for missing page parameter
page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

context = {
    'page_title': 'List of Applicants',
    'submitted_application_list': page_obj,
    'form': ApplicationlistBySessionForm(request.GET),  # Include full GET parameters
    'current_page': page_number,
    'has_more_pages': page_obj.has_next(),  # Check for next page
}
return render(request, 'admission/application_list_by_session.html', context)`


See JS Code:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var currentPage = 1;
  var isLoading = false;
  var hasMorePages = true; // Flag to track if there are more pages
  var totalApplicants = {{ count_submited_applications }}; // Total number of applicants
  var filterData = {}; // Object to store filter parameters (optional)

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      if (!isLoading && hasMorePages) {
        isLoading = true;
        currentPage++;
        var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

        // Add filter parameters to URL (if applicable)
        if (Object.keys(filterData).length > 0) {
          url += '?' + $.param(filterData);
        }

        url += '?page=' + currentPage;
  
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.trim() == "") {
            hasMorePages = false; // No more pages available
          } else {
            // Extract the table body content from the response
            var newEntries = $(data).find('#applicant-list tbody tr');
            var existingEntries = {}; // Object to store loaded entries

            newEntries.each(function() {
              var applicantData = $(this).text(); // Get applicant information (text content)

              // Check if applicant data already exists in loaded entries
              if (!existingEntries.hasOwnProperty(applicantData)) {
                existingEntries[applicantData] = true; // Add to loaded entries
                $('#applicant-list tbody').append($(this));
              }
            });
          }
          isLoading = false;

              // Check if all applicants have been loaded
              var totalLoadedApplicants = $('#applicant-list tbody tr').length;
              if (totalLoadedApplicants >= totalApplicants) {
                hasMorePages = false;
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
</script>



{% endblock %}


